# Prove that $(a+b)$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

> If $\frac {1} {a} + \frac {1} {b}= \frac {1} {c}$ ; $a,b,c$ are natural numbers with no common factors. Prove that $(a+b)$ is a perfect square.
>
> Source: Indian National Mathematics Olympiad by Rajeev Manocha.

What I have tried.

$\frac {1} {a} + \frac {1} {b}= \frac {1} {c}$

$\implies (a+b)c=ab$

$\implies a|(a+b)c$

But, $g.c.d(a,c)=1$

$\implies a|(a+b)$

$\implies a|b$

But, $g.c.d(a,b)=1$

$\therefore a=1$

In a similar way I have found $b=1$

But then $c=\frac {1} {2}$ which is contradicting that $c$ is a natural number.

The question asked to prove that $a+b$ is a square but I have proved that there is no integral solution of the given equation. Does my solution contain any error?

Comment: You are assuming that $gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,c)=gcd(b,c)=1$. But no common factors probably means $gcd(a,b,c)=1$.

Comment: Perhaps you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that $gcd(a,b,c)=1$.

Let $d=gcd(a,b)$. Then $a=da', b=db'$ and $gcd(d,c)=gcd(a',b')=1$.

$$ (a+b)c=ab \implies d(a'+b')c=d^2a'b' \implies (a'+b')c=da'b'$$

Now $gcd(a',b')=1$ implies that 
$$a'b'|c$$

So let $c=a'b'c'$, the equation becomes
$$(a'+b')c'=d$$

Since $gcd(c,d)=1$ you get $gcd(c',d)=1$ and hence, the above implies 
$$a'+b'=d \\
c'=1$$

Then 
$$a+b=da'+db'=d(a'+b')=d^2$$

**P.S.** Baring an embarassing mistake, if we set $n:=a', m:=b'$ we get $d=m+n$ and hence 
$$a=(m+n)m \\
b=(m+n)n \\
c=mn$$
This shows that the general solution to $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{c}$ with $gcd(a,b,c)=1$ is given by the above with $gcd(m,n)=1$.

It is not hard to see that $gcd(a,b,c)=1 \Leftrightarrow gcd(m,n)=1$.